# Creating a Simple Dictionary from a List

Tags: python

Sorry for asking a simple question:

I have the following list:

```
 x = ["one", "two", "three" ]
```

What is the best way to create this dictionary:

```
 {"one":1, "two":1, "three":1 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
{key: 1 for key in x}
```

Comment: I love it when answers are very easy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
print dict.fromkeys(["one","two","three"],1)
```

Is how I would do it ... if you really just want to make a dict from a list (to speed up searches maybe)

if you dont care what the value is you can just do

```
print dict.fromkeys(["one","two","three"])
```

and it will be the default `None`

this has the added benefit of working for python < 2.7 plus it is very easy to tell what you are doing , where as dict comprehensions always make me think of set comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to extrapolate and guess that you're looking for a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = ["one", "two", "three" ]
>>> Counter(x)
Counter({'three': 1, 'two': 1, 'one': 1})
```